# Why does spatial join on geodataframes return empty result?

Tags: python, spatial-join, geopandas, intersect, geodataframe

I have two `geodataframes` that I want to perform a spatial join on; one is points, one is polygons. They are both `dtype: int64`. They both have `.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}`. I have verified both of them in `ArcMap` that the points are indeed within the polys. I even performed an intersect between these points and polygons in `ArcMap` and it produced the correct new feature class (I have reasons for wanting to do this without `arpy`/manually in ArcMap). **Note: the points are from a shapefile and the polys are from a feature class
[image]

However, when I turn my centroid points and parcel polygons into `geodataframes` and use `.sjoin()`, it returns an empty `geodataframe`. I want the output to be a point-based geometry so that I can eventually turn it back into a point shapefile. I have tried:

```
intersect_test = gpd.sjoin(cents, polys, how='left', op='intersects')
```

and

```
intersect_test = gpd.sjoin(polys, cents, how='inner', op='intersects')
```

and

```
intersect_test = gpd.sjoin(polys, cents, how='right', op='intersects')
```

and

```
intersect_test = gpd.sjoin(cents, polys, how='left', op='intersects')
```

and pretty much every other configuration I can think of and it either returns the data for one of them, or returns a completely empty geodataframe result.

```
 intersect_test = gpd.sjoin(cents, polys, how='inner', op='intersects')
 intersect_test.count()
Out[126]: 
BLD_UNITS       0
LAND_USE_T      0
PARCEL_ID       0
PROP_IND_T      0
STORY_NBR       0
geometry        0
index_right     0
GEOID           0
CensusPop       0
CBArea          0
ST_FIPS         0
Shape_Length    0
Shape_Area      0
CO_FIPS         0
HU_Pop          0
Sq_Ft           0
dtype: int64
```

How can I resolve this without having to manually perform the intersect in ArcMap?

**EDIT**
Here's how I made my `geodataframes`. As I mentioned; one is a shapefile and one is a `.gdb feature class`. Question: Could this be due to `crs`-related problem?

```
#create poly gdf
cb_gdb = r"C:\Projects\Pop_Alloc\CensusBlocksStates.gdb"
cb_feat = "CBs_{}".format(state)
cents = gpd.read_file(cb_gdb, layer=cb_feat)
cents = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

#create point gdf. The parcel centroids are first created from a polygon 
gdf. The new gdf is written to a shapefile to be tested against the census 
block polygons (to make sure they do in fact fall within the boundaries of 
the census blocks (cbs)) and the new centroid gdf(its a 
`type='geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'`) is then used in the `.sjoin`       
cents = parcel_res_df
cents['geometry'] = 
cents['geometry'].representative_point()
cents_out_feat = r"C:\Projects\Pop_Alloc\{}_Res_centroids.shp".format(state)
cents = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
cents.to_file(cents_out_feat)
```

Comment: What you are trying should work. Can you show how you create the dataframes?

Comment: Just edited to include how I made the `.gdf`'s.

Comment: I would try [plotting them](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html) in geopandas and see if they overlap.

Comment: try it with overlay from geopandas http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html

Comment: Tried overlay but got: `TypeError: overlay only takes GeoDataFrames with (multi)polygon  geometries.` I have polys and points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a coordinate reference system issue. It is most likely caused by my census block feature class(aka `polys`) being in `ESRI:102008`. When I converted my polys feature class to a `geodataframe`, it showed `{}` when I ran `polys.crs`. Further investigation showed that the geometry looked like : `(POLYGON ((1385968.793600001 83806.20800000057...`, which was also incorrect. The solution required first finding the original `crs`, assigning the `'polys.crs'` to the correct `crs` and then reprojecting to the desired `crs`. To do this, I used `ogr`/`gdal`:

```
import ogr
def get_proj(gdb_input, fc ):
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB")
    gdb = driver.Open(gdb_input, 0)
    print('There are {} total layers in {}'.format(gdb.GetLayerCount(), gdb_input))

    for i in range(gdb.GetLayerCount()):
        layer = gdb.GetLayerByIndex(i)
        if layer.GetDescription() == fc:
            break
    in_crs = layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToProj4()
    return in_crs
    print('CRS = ', in_crs)

polys.crs = get_proj(poly_gdb, poly_name)
polys = cb_df.to_crs(cents.crs)
intersect = gpd.sjoin(ccents, polys, how='inner', op='intersects')
```

This returned the correctly intersected geodataframe. I have to say that I am surprised there is not documentation for what seems like a very common problem in using `Geopandas` with data from an `ESRI` context. Hope this helps.